# how to input value into an Excel cell using .Range.Offset(2, 0).Value = this value taken from an dynamic array(1)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The macro I write extracts ID's expiration dates from a word document and puts them into a dynamic array.

The macro is written in Excel VBA Editor and it's launched from Excel. It's searching currently opened word document and extracting the data from this document into the Excel spreadsheet.

Next it reads the expiration dates from the array and writes the into the Excel cells.
Usually it's 2-4 people, therefore it's 2-4 expiration dates.
This is what I got so far:

```
If startPos < 3 Or endPos < 3 Then
        MsgBox ("Client's names were not found!")
   'Id's expiration date extraction
   Else
        For Each Para In rng.Paragraphs
            'Extract id's expiration date
            'singleParaRng = Para.Range        'Here macro changes the contract text, without need.
            
            With singleParaRng.Find
               .Text = "<do dnia [0-9]{2} [A-ząćęłńóśżź]{3;12} [0-9]{4} roku>"
               .MatchWildcards = True
               .MatchCase = False
               .Forward = True
               .Execute
                 If .Found = True Then
                  aryExpiration(i) = singleParaRng.Text
                  lenght = Len(aryExpiration(i)) - 8        'Result = 21
                  aryExpiration(i) = Right(aryExpiration(i), Len(aryExpiration(i)) - 8)
                  aryExpiration(i) = Left(aryExpiration(i), Len(aryExpiration(i)) - 5)
                  aryExpiration(i) = Trim$(aryExpiration(i))
                  Debug.Print aryExpiration(i)
                 End If
            End With
            
            ActiveSheet.Range("M" & x).Value = aryExpiration(i)
            'This line above works fine but it's important 4 me to use the line below because it's more automated using the cell that will never change = $M$11
            ActiveSheet.scndRng.Offset(2, 0).Value = aryExpiration(i)          'Dim scndRng As Range
            'this line above is not working as expected;
            'It returns an error: Object doesn't support this property or method 
            x = x + 1
            i = i + 1
            
        Next Para
   End If
   'End of ID's expiration dates input
```

Please, help me make this line working - using `.Range.Offset(2, 0).Value`

```
ActiveSheet.scndRng.Offset(2, 0).Value = aryExpiration(i)          'Dimed scndRng As Range earlier in the beginning of the procedure;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this line??

I've checked [here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-offset-method.htm) and the code I'm writing exists.

What is the object that doesn't support this property or method??

As a response to @BigBen comments:
I have `scndRng` dimmed as range in the beginning of the procedure:

```
Dim startPos As Long
Dim endPos As Long
Dim parNmbr As Long
Dim lenght As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim scndRng As Range
Dim thrdRng As Range
Dim aryExpiration() As Variant
Dim aryNum() As Variant
```

And I have it set in the following lines:

```
'Assigning object variables and values
 Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")       'At its simplest, CreateObject creates an instance of an object,
 Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")     'whereas GetObject gets an existing instance of an object.
 Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument
 Set mySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 Set rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
 Set idExpDate = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
 Set singleParaRng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
 Set scndRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:O40").Find("data ważności", , xlValues)
 Set thrdRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:O40").Find("UDZIA", , xlValues)
```

Comment: Get rid of the `ActiveSheet.` Then `Dim scndRng As Range` and make sure you `Set` it too. `ActiveSheet.scndRng` is the problem.

Comment: Side note - please use the "ms-word" tag.

Comment: As a heads up you only assign a value - i to the array inside an ```if``` but set a value equal to that array index outside the```if``` that will cause problems if ```find``` fails.

Comment: @Warcupine Can you elaborate on this comment a little more please? What exactly should I change? Currently I have the ```i``` variable assigned a value = 1 outside the ```if  statement``` quite early in the beginning of the procedure. Is it good or bad??

Comment: ```i``` is incremented each loop, say ```i = 5``` you ```.find``` a match assign that index a value in the array then assign a range equal to that value, ```i``` is incremented to ```i = 6```. Next loop iteration your ```.find``` doesn't find a match, the array has no index 6 but you still assign a range value to ```aryExpiration(6)```

Comment: @Warcupine I don't understand what do you mean by a "range value" in your example?? Is it the initial ```i``` value I assign to it (in the very beginning of the macro), or is it the ```i = i + 1``` increment that's placed inside ```For Each Para .... Loop```.

Comment: ```i``` starts at 1, that's fine (though should probably be 0 as arrays are generally 0 indexed, but that's besides the point) it then gets incremented each iteration of the loop. the array assuming ```find``` is successful is now ```aryExpiration(1)``` you then ```ActiveSheet.Range("M" & x).Value = aryExpiration(1)``` but if ```find``` doesn't match the next iteration there will be no ```aryExpiration(2)``` but there is still ```ActiveSheet.Range("M" & x).Value = aryExpiration(2)``` that will throw a subscript out of range error.

Comment: @Warcupine  I've assigned ```i = 0``` in the beginning of the procedure and  ```ReDim aryExpiration(0 To custNmbr - 1)``` therefore, when I have 3 CustomerIDs, I have array indexes 0, 1 and 2 to store them. I know this was not the topic of your comments but this is what I've understood. I'll wait for the ```subscript out of range error``` to appear and I'll come back to your comments again. Maybe then I'll understand them better. I've put ```i = i + 1``` inside ```If .Found = True Then ... End If``` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following from your troublesome line: `Activesheet.`

Your variable `scndRng` already includes that level object, so adding it again doubles up and throws an error.

Comment: @Warcupine yes, I see now. The ActiveSheet part is doubled - once in the variable and again preceding it.